# "Did he tell you to do/say that?"

Tags: english-to-japanese

How would a grammatically correct sentence sound if you would want to say something like this?

> Did A tell you to do/say X?

> AさんはXを言ってって言ったの？

or

> AさんはXをしてって言ったの？

Comment: Your translations sound so good and natural to me... (You'd say AさんはX**って**言ってって言ったの？ instead of X**を** but this would depend on what the X is. You'd use を if X was a noun/pronoun, eg それを, その話を, そのことを etc., and って if X was a quoted statement... but you may already be aware of this!)

Answer (score 5):

> "Did A tell you to do/say X?"

ＡさんはあなたにＸをするように言いましたか？
ＡさんはあなたにＸと/を言うように言いましたか？

Your answers:

> 1. "AさんはXを言ってって言ったの？"
> 2. "AさんはXをしてって言ったの？"

- Almost perfect!
- Usually we omit *you*, but in this case, *A* told not *me* but *you*, so it's better not to omit *you* in order to avoid ambiguity in the translation like:
  「ＡさんはＸをしてって **あなたに**/**あんたに**/**お前に** 言ったの？」
- Double quotation marks which mark uttered phrases should be translated into 「」(鉤{かぎ}括弧{かっこ}). As for かぎかっこ, [here](https://yossense.com/blog-parenthesis/) is the way how to use it.